# Speech sysnthesise Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, speech-synthesis

I am getting Null pointer exception, I also know the reason. It is because synth is getting null value. What should i do to remove this? please help

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
           // Create a synthesizer for English
           Synthesizer synth = Central.createSynthesizer(new SynthesizerModeDesc(Locale.ENGLISH));

           // Get it ready to speak
           synth.allocate();

           synth.resume();

           // Speak the "Hello world" string

           synth.speakPlainText("Intiallizing the components, we are online and ready,sir", null);

          // Wait till speaking is done

          synth.waitEngineState(Synthesizer.QUEUE_EMPTY);

         // Clean up

         synth.deallocate();

    } catch (Exception e) {

         e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Comment: There is no Synthesizer that satisfies your requirements. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/speech/forDevelopers/jsapi-doc/javax/speech/Central.html#createSynthesizer%28javax.speech.EngineModeDesc%29 Have you tried Central.createSynthesizer(null); for the default?

Comment: @RAM same error is there "NullPointerException", problem is that always synth is having null value

Answer (score 2):

Even after including all the jar files, in your code, you ought to set property for dictionary and set engine as well. You can do this by including this block of code inside try:

```
System.setProperty("freetts.voices","com.sun.speech.freetts.en.us.cmu_us_kal.KevinVoiceDirectory");
       Central.registerEngineCentral("com.sun.speech.freetts.jsapi.FreeTTSEngineCentral");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `null` check to avoid `NullPointerException`

```
if(synth != null)
{

synth.allocate();
synth.resume();
synth.speakPlainText("Intiallizing the components, we are online and ready,sir", null);
synth.waitEngineState(Synthesizer.QUEUE_EMPTY);
synth.deallocate();

}
```

Comment: Although i can use this but the problem is i am always getting the value of synth equal to null.why so ?

Comment: mean u want to set the locale as english but getting excetion?

Comment: Yep. whatever i m selecting as Locale(Locale.UK,Locale.US) it gives synth = null.

Comment: Can u try this Synthesizer synth = Central.createSynthesizer(
new SynthesizerModeDesc(
null, // engine name
"general", // mode name
Locale.US, // locale
null, // running
null) // voice
);

Comment: can u provide me the path from where i can download the jar of javax.speech.synthesis ?

Comment: sure 
http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/download/
please reply if you get some output :)

Comment: Do u try with default locale like Synthesizer synth = Central.createSynthesizer(null); ?? I m unable to download due to jar size >20 mb

Comment: This page contain gud examples https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/04/13/vocal-java.html can u try this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47387/discussion-between-niks-tyagi-and-codepad)

Answer (score -1):

I guess the problem is you haven't added the speech synthesizers. Download FreeTTS(https://sourceforge.net/projects/freetts/). Extract the zip file to a folder. Inside the folder you will see jsapi.exe. Run it. It will create jsapi.jar. Add all the jar files to your classpath. And then try the below example.

```
import com.sun.speech.freetts.Voice;
import com.sun.speech.freetts.VoiceManager;

public class Text_to_speech {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text = "Voice check!";

    Voice voice;
    VoiceManager voiceManager = VoiceManager.getInstance();
    voice = voiceManager.getVoice("kevin");
    voice.allocate();
    voice.speak(text);

 }


}
```

`

Comment: Much better, thanks. (Not my downvote btw, I lack domain knowledge to vote on this post.)

Comment: Tats ok. I don't feel bad for that.

Comment: I deserve the down vote for my previous answer. And thanks for you  to point my mistake.